# How to change the ratio in a figure's input

Tags: floats

I've got this in an org-mode file:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \newlength\figureheight 
    \newlength\figurewidth 
    \setlength\figureheight{6cm} 
    \setlength\figurewidth{8cm}
    \input{3formulae.tikz}
    \caption{A graph}
    \label{fig:graph}
\end{figure}
```

It imports `3formulae.tikz`, a simple x-y graph, which was produced with GeoGebra export. However, upon export to HTML or Latex, the width and height of the produced graph image is distorted toward the vertical. How could I get a 1:1 ratio back? I realize this is the strange world of org-mode stuff, hence, how would a normal ratio modification go inside a `\begin` section?

Comment: there is a command in the `graphicx` package, available to `tikz`, which is `\scalebox{<h-scale>}[<v-scale>]{<content>}` that might, with some trial and error, be able to resolve the issue for you, depending on what is in `3formulae.tikz`.

Comment: The information given is pretty incomplete, so it is hard to give an `org-mode` solution or a LaTeX solution. For conversion questions, usually at least the raw input code. (Generally, I like to see the input and resulting output, but I assume that's because I lack the deep intuitions others have.)

Comment: My whole motivation for doing a `\input` is because the `.tikz` file is huge. Too big to simply paste into my orgmode file. GeoGebra sometimes just brute-forces a picture with gazillions of `\drawline`s. Looking at the TikZ code, yes, it's squishing things horizontally. I was simply wondering if in my *figure* code could correct and stretch out the horizontal again. I think the moral of this story is forget being clever with embedding raw TikZ code in orgmode and just go with pngs.